# Custom 404 Page not found in abp framework

Tags: abp

I am using ABP.io 4.1 with razor pages.

Is there any way to customize the 404-page? Right now it just says *[404] Error!*.

Would be nice to at least adjust the message, but would also be great if a razor page could be loaded with some content and logic to perhaps store the missing url for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom error page with name `Error.cshtml` and put it in Pages folder of your Web project.

This is an example of how you can override the default error page
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/docs/app/VoloDocs.Web/Pages/Error.cshtml

alternatively you can remove the existing Error middle ware and add yours

[image]